# Как передать переменную из метода в другой метод?

Tags: python

Создал класс.В этом классе у меня есть методы.

```
class boilerpipe_parser:

    def __init__(self):
        # < Подключение к базе данных.
        self.connection = pymysql.connect(host = 'localhost',
                             user = 'root',
                             password = '',
                             db = 'news_portal',
                             charset = 'utf8',
                             autocommit = True)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def get_resources(self):
         # < Запрос правил выдергивания из таблицы resource контента.
        self.cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM `resource` where `resource_id` = 76')
        resources = self.cursor.fetchall()
        # < Перебор данных из select запроса.
        for resource in resources:
            res_id = resource[0]
            resource_url = resource[3]
            resource_links = resource[4]
            link_rules = resource[5]
            resource_check = resource[4]

            link_rule = link_rules.split(',')
            return resource_links

    def get_html(self):
        self.r = requests.get()

        return self.r.text
```

Как передать переменную в качестве аргументов  `resource_links` в `get_html` метод?
Чтобы было так:

> ```
> def get_html(self, resource_links):
>         self.r = requests.get(resource_links)
>         return self.r.text
> ```

Я делал так:

```
def get_html(self, resource_links):
        self.r = requests.get(resource_links)
        print(self.r.text)
        return self.r.text
```

И вызывал этот метод таким образом

```
# < Вызываю объект класса
parser =boilerpipe_parser()
# < Вызываю метод класса
parser.get_html(resource_links)
```

В следствии чего выходит ошибка `NameError: name 'resource_links' is not defined` то что resource_links не определенна.
Как передать в качестве аргумента переменную из одного метода в другой метод?

Comment: А где она определена в вашем коде?

Comment: @mkkik, она определена в методе `get_resource` внутри цикла

Comment: Вы же в курсе про области видимости переменных?

Comment: @mkkik,конечно в курсе.И из-за этого у меня возник вопрос.Как передать переменную в другой метод

Comment: Чтобы что-то передать куда-то, необходимо, чтобы это что-то уже существовало в **текущей области видимости**.

Comment: Можно прямо в функции вызвать метод: *def get_html(self): **resource_links = self.get_resources()** self.r = requests.get(resource_links) return self.r.text*

Comment: @Nobody, благодарю за комментарий

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    def get_html(self, links):

        self.r = requests.get(links)

        return self.r.text
```

При вызове этого метода в качестве переменной и указываешь метод get_resources()

```
u = boilerpipe_parser()

u.get_html(u.get_resources())
```

Comment: Ваше ответ некорректен.Пожалуйста прочитайте внимательнее мой вопрос

Comment: исправил код, добавил переменную